# How to show that an event is in the tail $\sigma$ field

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

May I know why the event $\{\text{lim sup}_n \frac{S_n}{n}>b\}$ is in the tail $\sigma$-field but $\{\text{lim sup}_n S_n>b\}$ is not? where $X_i$'s are real-valued and need not be independent.

I can see that $\{\text{lim sup}_n S_n>b\}$ is affected by a change in values of the first $n$ random variables and this is true for any $n$ and is hence not in the tail $\sigma-$field but don't understand why $\{\text{lim sup}_n \frac{S_n}{n}>b\}$ is unaffected by the first $n$ random variables? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the values of first $n$ $X_i$’s are changed, $S_n$ is changed by a finite number $a$ for all sufficiently large $n$. Since $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac a{n}=0$, the event $\{\limsup_n\frac{S_n}{n}>b\}$ is unaffected.

Answer (score 1):

For any $m < n$ $$\frac{S_n}{n} = \frac{S_m}{n} + \frac{S_n-S_m}{n}$$ which is the sum of one term that tends to zero as $n\to\infty$ and another in $\sigma(X_k : k>m)$